# What are the NitroPDF alternatives for mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

[NitroPDF](http://www.nitropdf.com/) is an excellent software for various kinds of formatting, merging and splitting of PDF files but it is available only for machines running windows OS. What are good alternatives for such softwares on machines running OS X ?

The main pdf related features that I am looking for are :-

1. **Editing** : Allows to edit a pdf
2. **Merging** : Allows simple merging of multiple of pdf files into one
3. **Splitting** : Splitting of an existing pdf into multiple pdf
4. **Print** : Change a pdf from 1 page per side to a pdf of 4 (or more) pages per side.
5. **Highlighting** : Allows to highlight a part of the pdf.

I am not sure if the default pdf viewer *Preview* provides all these features.

Comment: OSX's Preview is quite good at handling PDF files. Did you give it a try ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about which features you are looking for and why the standard Preview app doesn't match your needs?